# MYSQL search result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a code, in which there are users will search for the name from MySQL.

First the mysql should search in **first_name**, then go to **last_name** for the same search option and then display results. **(From both First_name and Last_name)**

I tried but it showed me only the results from first name

Please help me.

Here is the code:-

```
try {
  $keyword = trim($_GET["keyword"]);
  if ($keyword <> "" ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 AND "
            . " (first_name LIKE :keyword) ORDER BY first_name ";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(":keyword", $keyword."%");

  } elseif ($keyword <> "" ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 AND "
            . " (last_name LIKE :keyword) ORDER BY first_name ";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(":keyword", $keyword."%");

  }else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 ORDER BY first_name ";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
  }

  $stmt->execute();
  $total_count = count($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Comment: Why do you have `WHERE 1 AND`? Just curious to know.

Comment: Use `OR` and not `AND` if one fails, both will with `AND`.

Comment: Your `elseif` doesn't make any sense. You'll never get there.

Comment: @jeroen that too ;-) query needs to be modified to use `OR` and in one query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- how to have the code then..?

Comment: just a few tips: single quotes are faster, else if as two separate words are faster, and your if / elseif condition are the exact same

Comment: @Fred-ii- Possibly, but I read it as *if no results are found, only then check the last-name*. So the OP would need to execute the first query before checking for the last-name.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs **if** has **first_name** and **elseif** has **last_name**

Comment: `SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col1=x OR col2=y`. You don't need all of those other queries, you can do this in one go.

Comment: @BabaluPandey `if ($keyword <> "" ) {` is your first if and your second is `} elseif ($keyword <> "" ) {` - where is the difference?

Comment: if it's of any comfort, I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you always helped me out, and I am confident that you will help me this time too.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs what should I use in **elseif** then

Comment: @jeroen will this edit help you out?

Comment: @BabaluPandey Definitely :-) To solve your problem, first you need to check for the first-name like you are doing now (without the `elseif`). Then, if you find no results, you do the same again but for the last-name.

Comment: @BabaluPandey well, it depends, most people would have first name and last name as two separate inputs and variables to search for

Comment: @jeroen you are understanding me now... and I have edited more as your previous comment ** if no results are found, only then check the last-name.**

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I couldn't get you..!

Comment: @jeroen are you getting me..

Comment: @BabaluPandey essentially, break up your code into more variables, this will make things a lot more easier for your conditionals

Comment: @Fred-ii- sir can you help me out

Comment: @jeroen sir waiting for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid posting **same question** in other ways, edit the same question.

You asked the same question in [MYSQL OR not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859318/mysql-or-not-working)

Hope this will really help you:-

```
try {
  $keyword = trim($_GET["keyword"]);
  if ($keyword <> "" ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 AND "
            . " (first_name LIKE :keyword OR last_name LIKE :keyword) ORDER BY first_name ";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(":keyword", $keyword."%");
  }else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 ORDER BY first_name ";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
  }

  $stmt->execute();
  $total_count = count($stmt->fetchAll());
```

I have also answered your new repeated question https://stackoverflow.com/a/44859408/7678788