# MYSQL OR not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code in which `OR` is not working

```
try {
  $keyword = trim($_GET["keyword"]);
  if ($keyword <> "" ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 AND "
            . " (first_name OR last_name LIKE :keyword) ORDER BY first_name ";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(":keyword", $keyword."%");
```

It only search from `last_name` and not from `first_name`.

I need that it should search for both **last_name** and **first_name**.

Comment: `(first_name LIKE :keyword1 OR last_name LIKE :keyword2)` Isn't it obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proper code is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 AND "
        . " (first_name LIKE :keyword1 OR last_name LIKE :keyword2) ORDER BY first_name ";
$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":keyword1", $keyword."%");
$stmt->bindValue(":keyword2", $keyword."%");
```

**Notice** that you **cannot** have more than **one** placeholder with same name. That's why I use `keyword1` and `keyword2` and bind same value to them.

Comment: keyword1 and keyword2 values should be in single quotes

Comment: @TSungur and why?

Comment: Because it will be a string value and sql strings are surrounded with quotes?

Comment: "You know nothing Jon Snow"

Comment: Sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 AND "
        . " (first_name LIKE :keyword OR last_name LIKE :keyword) ORDER BY first_name ";
```

Answer (score 1):

This time you took extra efforts and tried more, yes this is more clear than, [MYSQL search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845731/mysql-search-result).

```
try {
  $keyword = trim($_GET["keyword"]);
  if ($keyword <> "" ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 AND "
        . " (first_name LIKE :keyword OR last_name LIKE :keyword) ORDER BY first_name ";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(":keyword", $keyword."%");
```

Hope this will help you out.

And yes try to edit the same question, avoid asking the same question in a different way.

I have answered that question too https://stackoverflow.com/a/44859438/7678788

Comment: I was forced to repeat it as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845731/mysql-search-result was not fully active now.

Comment: @Chiru read notice in my answer and edit yours. Your code will __not__ work.